# Springs/Struts in TabBarApp Won't Show Whole UIImages?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, retina-display

I've been everywhere and I can't find a solution. I have to submit this app tonight, only to discover three nights ago I couldn't submit it without supporting 4inch Retina.
Didn't even know of it until now.

So here's my problem. Springs and Struts. I have a "main menu" image of 6 people to come perform at a local event in my town. They fit WONDERFULLY on the Retina (I've tested it on the simulator since my iPhone is 4s (3.5 inch screen)). I haven't been allowed to touch Storyboard until this point.

My layout is simple: 2x3 column/rows of square UIImages.
Problem: Corner images won't fit onto the screen. Each box is equal height: 320x455.

So some of my images are skimmed off. for example: My top left image (Image_seven.png) is at X:86 Y:80. Part of the top is skimmed off.

Does anyone know how I can use springs and struts to adjust the images to fit onto my screen?

Thanksa bunch!

I can't get the second image in.... it keeps changing the other one automatically. Let me try again. [image: This is my problem:]

Comment: I think you don't need Spring/Struts for positioning images. You need to look into css

Comment: CSS is a web technology that will not help you.  I think we need screenshots as I am having trouble visualizing the problem.

Comment: @Techgirl-52 A screenshot would help. Also, is your whole UI designed in a storyboard? You could set the struts for the edges that are getting clipped and remove everything else. Ex. upper left hand corner image would have a strut on the left and top edges and no where else, so that the spacing remains constant across bounds changes.

Comment: mea culpa @Techgirl-52 , wrong domain for me , inconvenience caused is deeply regretted

Comment: Please consider updating the title to something meaningful and related to the actual issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I have updated the title. I'm horrible with naming subjects so please let me know if it's still poorly named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I'm not sure I understand why things will not fit, generally with a row of 2x3 images you should have them all in a UIView - then make the corner images have struts going to the nearest sides, the middle images having struts to the closest edge - and all of them having "springs" (the center lines) going in both directions to allow the boxes to resize.

Also make sure the UIView that all of the images are in (and the UIViews that may be contained in) all have Autoresize set to YES (or checked in interface builder) or things will still not resize.

Edit:  Thanks for the screenshot.

It seems like your center view is not being resized, which is why it's cut off top and bottom.  Whatever view is holding all those images (either a UIView or a table view), make sure it also has all of the "springs" selected, and also all of the struts.  Then as the tab bar expands the view your center view should properly resize with it.

Another thing to be aware of that may cause issues, is that in viewDidLoad, your view will still be whatever size you have it in a xib file - so if you do any placement or size calculations in viewDidLoad, they will be wrong if they look at the bounds or frame of self.view.

Comment: It still doesn't automatically fit....I do think the cause is because it's a Tab Bar App (I didn't think about mentioning this until now) with Navigation Controllers. So you've got a Title bar on top and a tab bar on the bottom. // Is there a way I can have it shrink a little bit to fit? It's wonderful on Retina 4inch... 3.5 is having issues.

So those few extra inches are in the app, just are cut off by the bars.

Comment: Is there a way I can have it automatically adjust above the bars so it doesn't interfere with Retina 4inch? I've never programed for both before and I'm afraid of jeopardizing the project.
Thanksa bunch!